# Azure SQL Server - Firewalls and virtual networks - Azure ignoring my virtual network connection

Tags: sql-server, firewall, azure, virtual-network

I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL server instance via a virtual network. I have it set up and it's connecting fine. Then I added the vnet to the Firewalls and virtual networks. Endpoint status is 'Enabled' the state is 'Ready'. I've added Microsoft.sql as a service endpoint.

However, when I try to connect to the server via SSMS, it completely ignores all this and instead asks me to allow my personal IP address. I don't want to have to add an IP address for every user who wants access, and I don't understand why Azure is just ignoring my virtual network rule. It's infuriating.

I already tried all this with a SQL VM, that was even more of a disaster.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

[image: screenshot of f/w rules]

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, you mentioned that you added the vNet to the firewall, but then talk about running SSMS on your personal IP. Where is SSMS running, on a machine in that vNet or on your local machine?

Comment: SSMS is running on my own machine. I've connected to a vnet via a VPN connection so shouldn't it go via the VPN instead of using my own IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Service endpoints do not support traffic going over a VPN connection to the network endpoints, see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview#secure-azure-service-access-from-on-premises).

To allow access from your on-premises machine you have two options.

1. Use the "Client IP Address" section to add the IP's of your on premises egress point. Usually most corporate networks only have a few egress IP's, but if you have lot's this can obviously be painful to maitain.
2. Look to use Private Link instead of service endpoints. Private link provides a private IP for your SQL database on your vNet, and this does support access from VPN and Express Route connections. You can see how this works [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview).

Comment: The Private link doesn't work, I set one up and it hasn't made any difference, but thanks for the help anyway. EDIT: This is probably because of what Roberto said, that it'll only allow connections from within VMs which isn't what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Private link definitely does work, I've used it for this scenario a number of times. If your traffic is not being routed via the vNet then you need to look at your VPN configuration to make sure it is actually trying to route traffic from SSMS over the vNet

Comment: How do I do that? I'm in the user vpn configuration for my virtual network gateway on azure and there's nothing to indicate what kind of traffic it is or isn't routing.

Answer (score 0):

Azure VPN is split tunneled at the moment. So what happens is that the authentication with Azure SQL runs over the VPN. But the actual connection still runs over the open internet.

You can add a private endpoint to the virtual network. Frustratingly, that will only allow access to any VMs on the virtual network to the Azure SQL Server.

With an SQL managed instance, however,  connecting over an Azure VPN to the SQl server is actually possible. The difference being that a managed instance is much more expensive. So I suspect this is Microsoft trying to upsell people to the more expensive offering.

That is not a huge help to you, understandably. But there are still things we can do, depending on your aims.

My current setup  to allow my company to work from home has been to run an OpenVPN VM in the virtual network and have everyone connect to that. This gives you 1 IP address to add to the firewall. And all clients will share that address.

The openVPN server is available in the Azure marketplace (and is free - you just pay compute costs for the VM). You'll need to get licenses from https://openvpn.net/.

If you just want a single Ip address to add to the firewall, then this should be sufficient.

If your aim is to have the entire connection end to end over the VPN, that is still something that I'm working on. I'm still working on getting the private endpoint to work over the openVPN connection.

Hope this helps

Roberto

Comment: I will look in to this, thank you for your help :)